# Spring Integration - File Message Flow

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using the file and ftp features of Spring Integration to implement a flow which sees all files 
written to directory encrypted and then ftp'ed to a target directory. The payload of the message is a file

```
File Inbound Poller -> Custom Encryption -> Outbound FTP -> Handle Original File
```

The 'Custom Encryption' service takes in a file name, and then returns the name of the encrypted file. The Outbound FTP service works and on success or failure of the transfer, the encrypted file name is moved to a specific folder.

The new requirement is i need to move the original file name rather than the encrypted one. I'm unsure what is the correct way implement this or what options i have?

```
File Inbound Poller -> Custom Encryption -> Outbound FTP
                    |                               |
                    >                               >     -> Handle Original File
```

The first idea I've considered using the Splitter/Aggregator pattern to generate a second message which is re-aggreated after the outbound ftp stage but this seems incorrect since the splitter is not generating two distinct messages, rather duplicating the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it, including...

1. Make the first channel a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` subscribe the encrypter with `order="1"` and the handler `order="2"`. The handler will only be called after the other flow completes normally.
2. Add a `<header-enricher/>` before the encryption service, to copy the original file to a header `<header name="orig" expression="payload"/>` and then use the header in the downstream code.

The first is like your "splitter" comment - effectively allowing 2 flows to process the same message.

Comment: thanks. i had thought of using the header as per option 2, but felt this was maybe cheating a little, since i didn't want to add a load of name/values to the header. In terms of option 1, in order to return the value of the ftp operation, i'd set the header value again?

Comment: last question - for a 'request-handler-advice-chain' is it possible to have both a RequestHandlerRetryAdvice and ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice bean in the chain?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "FTP result"; if it succeeds, the thread will return normally, if it throws an exception it won't call the second subscriber (by default - it can be overridden with 'ignore-failures'). Regarding headers - this is a common approach - for example, the <file-to-string-transformer/> does the same thing. In fact, we even provide a constant (FileHeaders.ORIGINAL_FILE).

Comment: Regarding <advice-chain/> yes - it's a (nested) chain of advices. Of course, in this case, order is important. Typically, in this case, the retry advice would be AFTER the onFail/onSuccess expression advice. Note, however, if, for some reason, you need the retry advice first, there is a bug in 2.2.0 (fixed in 2.2.1) where the other advices after the retry advice were not invoked on the retries.